# Resolving issues in SonarQube does not affect warnings reported by SonarLint

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

If I change status of an issue in SonarQube 5.4 to "Resolved (Won't fix)" or "Resolved (False Positive)", and update data in SonarLint/Eclipse from the server, SonarLint 2.1.0 still reports the warning.
Is that as designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet. We will be working on it in the next couple of months or so.

Meanwhile, you can watch it and even vote for it: ["Don't show resolved issues in connected mode" - SLE-72](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-72)